# How to trigger fops poll function from the kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a kernel driver which logs some spi data in a virtual file using debugfs.

My main goal is to be able to "listen" for incomming data from userspace using for example `$ tail -f /sys/kernel/debug/spi-logs` which is using select to wait for new data on the debugfs file.

I've implemented the fops poll function in the driver and when I am trying to get the data from the userspace, the poll function is never called even though there is new data available in the kernel to be read.

I assume that the poll function never gets called because the debugfs file never gets actually written.

My question is, is there a way to trigger the poll function from the kernel space when new data is available?

EDIT: Added an example

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
#include <linux/poll.h>

struct module_ctx {
    struct wait_queue_head wq;
};

struct module_ctx module_ctx;

static ssize_t debugfs_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *off)
{
    // simulate no data left to read for now
    return 0;
}

static __poll_t debugfs_poll(struct file *filp, struct poll_table_struct *wait) {
    struct module_ctx *module_hdl;
    __poll_t mask = 0;

    module_hdl = filp->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_private;
    
    pr_info("CALLED!!!");

    poll_wait(filp, &module_hdl->wq, wait);

    if (is_data_available_from_an_external_ring_buffer())
        mask |= POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;

    return mask;
}

loff_t debugfs_llseek(struct file *filp, loff_t offset, int orig)
{
    loff_t pos = filp->f_pos;

    switch (orig) {
        case SEEK_SET:
            pos = offset;
            break;
        case SEEK_CUR:
            pos += offset;
            break;
        case SEEK_END:
            pos = 0; /* Going to the end => to the beginning */
            break;
        default:
            return -EINVAL;
    }

    filp->f_pos = pos;

    return pos;
}

static const struct file_operations debugfs_fops = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .read = debugfs_read,
        .poll = debugfs_poll,
        .llseek = debugfs_llseek,
};

static int __init rb_example_init(void)
{
    struct dentry *file;

    init_waitqueue_head(&module_ctx.wq);

    file = debugfs_create_file("spi_logs", 0666, NULL, &module_ctx,
                               &debugfs_fops);
    if (!file) {
        pr_err("qm35: failed to create /sys/kernel/debug/spi_logs\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit

rb_example_exit(void) {

}

module_init(rb_example_init);
module_exit(rb_example_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Mihai Pop");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");
```

Using `tail -f /sys/kernel/debug/spi_logs`, the poll function never gets called

Comment: "I assume that the poll function never gets called because the debugfs file never gets actually written." - No, that assumption is incorrect. A `poll` function is called whenever program uses `select`, `poll`,  or similar syscalls. Probably, something wrong with your **code**, e.g. in its `read` function. Please, add your code into the question post, so we will be able to help you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added an example

Comment: It is better to use **newline**-terminating strings in `printk` and related functions: otherwise the string could be printed with a great delay.

Comment: @Tsyvarev true but that’s not what’s happening here

Answer (score 0):

Semantic of `poll` is to return whenever encoded operations (`read` and/or `write`) on a file would **return without block**. In case of `read` operation, "block" means:

- If `read` is called in nonblocking mode (field `f_flags` of the `struct file` has  flag `O_NONBLOCK` set), then it returns `-EAGAIN`.
- If `read` is called in blocking mode, then it puts a thread into the waiting state.

As you can see, your `read` function doesn't follow that convention and returns 0, which means EOF. So the caller has no reason to call `poll` after that.

---

Semantic of `-f` option for `tail`:

> ... not stop when **end of file** is reached, but rather to wait ...

is about the situation, when `read` returns 0, but the program needs to wait.

As you can see, `poll` semantic is not suitable for such wait. Instead, such programs use `inotify` mechanism.